# ORA-00933 couldnt find what im missing

Tags: sql, oracle

Why below query returns SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended:

```
Update xla_events
SET 
EVENT_DATE='01-OCT-2019’, 
transaction_date='01-OCT-2019’,
REFERENCE_DATE_1='01-OCT-2019’,
CREATED_BY = -11111
WHERE application_id = 707
AND Event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM XE_Sweep_bkup_orcl1);
```

Comment: Replace `’` with `'` and start using a normal plain text editor that doesn't use "smart quotes" to edit your SQL statements.

Comment: I agree with the  anonymous galloper, you need to use a text editor which is more suited to coding. There are free decent ones for whichever OS you use. One which supports syntax highlighting would have helped here. As you can see from the simple highlighting imposed by StackOverflow, `transaction_date` is coloured as a string literal, which is a nudge that the quote-mark at the end of the previous literal has not in fact terminated it  .

Comment: As an aside, if the columns you're updating are of DATE format, please don't use a string value to update them with. Instead, you should explicitly convert the strings into a date using `to_date()` or the `DATE` literal, e.g. `to_date('01/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` or `DATE 2019-10-01`

Comment: `'01-OCT-2019'` is a **string**, not a date. Use [DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) literals or [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and solutions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes you use aren't really "single quotes" Oracle accepts, but some "fancy" single quotes (the ones that you get when, for example, write code in MS WOrd and then copy/paste into a tool you use to work with Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

it seems you your ending quote was different

```
Update xla_events
SET 
EVENT_DATE='01-OCT-2019', 
transaction_date='01-OCT-2019',
REFERENCE_DATE_1='01-OCT-2019',
CREATED_BY = -11111
WHERE application_id = 707
AND Event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM XE_Sweep_bkup_orcl1);
```

Comment: ooh nice catch. thank you